# Jenkins Pod initialized but has has failed plugins which is not allowing any jobs to execute

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

After the pod was restarted the jenkins container shows its running but it has all these failed errors in its log, due to these errors unable to execute any job. What will be the ideal suggestion to get these fixed. Should i just follow the suggestion and update the plugins to what the error is prompting for or something else.

Jenkins container image is
Image:         jenkins/jenkins:2.319.2

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: JAXB plugin (2.3.6-1)
 - Update required: JavaBeans Activation Framework (JAF) API (1.2.0-2) to be updated to 1.2.0-3 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.439+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Nodes and Processes v1139.v252a_e12e8463 (workflow-durable-task-step)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Nodes and Processes (1139.v252a_e12e8463)
 - Update required: SCM API Plugin (595.vd5a_df5eb_0e39) to be updated to 602.v6a_81757a_31d2 or higher
 - Update required: Durable Task Plugin (493.v195aefbb0ff2) to be updated to 496.va67c6f9eefa7 or higher
 - Update required: Script Security Plugin (1131.v8b_b_5eda_c328e) to be updated to 1138.v8e727069a_025 or higher
 - Update required: Pipeline: API (1136.v7f5f1759dc16) to be updated to 1144.v61c3180fa_03f or higher
 - Update required: Structs Plugin (308.v852b473a2b8c) to be updated to 318.va_f3ccb_729b_71 or higher
 - Update required: Pipeline: Step API (622.vb_8e7c15b_c95a_) to be updated to 625.vd896b_f445a_f8 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.687+0000 [id=31]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Java JSON Web Token (JJWT) Plugin v0.11.5-77.v646c772fddb_0 (jjwt-api)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Java JSON Web Token (JJWT) Plugin (0.11.5-77.v646c772fddb_0)
 - Update required: Jackson 2 API Plugin (2.13.1-246.va8a9f3eaf46a) to be updated to 2.13.3-285.vc03c0256d517 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.694+0000 [id=31]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Basic Steps v2.24 (workflow-basic-steps)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.24)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Nodes and Processes (1139.v252a_e12e8463)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.696+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Milestone Step v101.vd572fef9d926 (pipeline-milestone-step)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Milestone Step (101.vd572fef9d926)
 - Update required: Pipeline: API (1136.v7f5f1759dc16) to be updated to 1143.v2d42f1e9dea_5 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.697+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: Declarative v1.9.3 (pipeline-model-definition)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: Declarative (1.9.3)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.24)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.698+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline v581.v0c46fa_697ffd (workflow-aggregator)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline (581.v0c46fa_697ffd)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.24)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.780+0000 [id=31]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin GitHub Branch Source Plugin v2.11.4 (github-branch-source)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: GitHub Branch Source Plugin (2.11.4)
 - Failed to load: Java JSON Web Token (JJWT) Plugin (0.11.5-77.v646c772fddb_0)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.781+0000 [id=31]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin HTML Publisher plugin v1.30 (htmlpublisher)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: HTML Publisher plugin (1.30)
 - Update required: Matrix Project Plugin (1.20) to be updated to 758.v7a_ea_491852f3 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.783+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean v1.24.8 (blueocean-pipeline-api-impl)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean (1.24.8)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Nodes and Processes (1139.v252a_e12e8463)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.784+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean v1.24.8 (blueocean-git-pipeline)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean (1.24.8)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean (1.24.8)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.789+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries v38.v445716ea_edda_ (pipeline-github-lib)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Pipeline: GitHub Groovy Libraries (38.v445716ea_edda_)
 - Update required: Git plugin (4.10.3) to be updated to 4.11.1 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.799+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin HTTP Request Plugin v1.15 (http_request)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: HTTP Request Plugin (1.15)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.24)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:45.801+0000 [id=28]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Docker Pipeline v1.27 (docker-workflow)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Docker Pipeline (1.27)
 - Failed to load: Pipeline: Basic Steps (2.24)
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:46.121+0000 [id=30]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin Webhook Step Plugin v173.vfa_b_93560b_977 (webhook-step)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Webhook Step Plugin (173.vfa_b_93560b_977)
 - Update required: Script Security Plugin (1131.v8b_b_5eda_c328e) to be updated to 1138.v8e727069a_025 or higher
 - Update required: Pipeline: Step API (622.vb_8e7c15b_c95a_) to be updated to 625.vd896b_f445a_f8 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-06-22 12:42:46.126+0000 [id=29]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin SSH Build Agents plugin v1.821.vd834f8a_c390e (ssh-slaves)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: SSH Build Agents plugin (1.821.vd834f8a_c390e)
 - Update required: Credentials Plugin (1074.v60e6c29b_b_44b_) to be updated to 1087.1089.v2f1b_9a_b_040e4 or higher
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:1016)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:535)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue following below steps.
Steps to take if it occurs in future

a. Grab the failed plugin from the log output of jenkins-pod by running kubectl logs jenkins-0 -c=jenkins -n ci

b. Browse plugins.jenkins.io/failed plugin to check for compatibility with the installed jenkins version.

c. Update the failed plugins from the plugin-manager on jenkins UI.

d. Update just two or three failed plugins to check if those plugins go away from the log output of the pod.

e. After plugin update click the restart checkbox.

f. Lastly run any pipeline that validates that jobs ran.

After every cold-start of jenkins the deployment jobs will take longer to finish, once it has cached those jobs they will start running quickly.